# Sequelize: password cannot be an array or an object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Why do I get this error : password cannot be an array or an object, when I try to add a new user, if my password is of type String, I hash it, and I store it, but I still get this error, which doesn't make much sense: `SequelizeValidationError: string violation: password cannot be an array or an object`

```
                // Hash password with bcrypt
                const hashedPassword = passwordController.hashPassword(password, 10);

                // Create new User
                await User.create({
                    first_name: firstName,
                    last_name: lastName,
                    username: username,
                    email: email,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                    date_joined: new Date(),
                    role_id: role
                }).then(user => {
                    // Success
                    return done(null, user, req.flash('message', 'Successfully added user'));
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    return done(null, false);
                });
```

Comment: Have you logged your hashed password? You didn't show your hashing method. Bcrypt uses a promise, are you using it as such? If not then likely your hashedpassword is a promise object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to hash your password in this way

```
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
```